# Как вернуть boolean при добавлении в таблицу postgres?

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть скрипт который добавляет пользователя в таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        id SERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        username TEXT NOT NULL,
        login TEXT NOT NULL,
        password TEXT NOT NULL,
        email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        create_date Timestamp,
        success_level CHARACTER(10) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT user_unique UNIQUE (login, password)
);
```

Сам скрипт добавления:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username, login, password, email, create_date, success_level)
VALUES (DEFAULT, (?), (?), (?), (?), now()::timestamp, (?))
```

Я хочу сэкономить на отдельном запросе о существовании пользователя с такой парой логин/пароль.

Как мне модифицировать скрипт так что-бы он возвращал `true` или `false` в случае успеха или провала операции в связи с ограничением `CONSTRAINT user_unique UNIQUE (login, password)`?

Comment: В случае нарушения ограничения будет кинуто исключение. Используйте `try catch`

Comment: В какой среде вы выполняете запросы?

Comment: @0xdb java JDBC Driver

Comment: @Sergey вы имеете в виду try/catch в postgres или в методе который запрос отправляет??

Comment: В методе конечно

Comment: @Sergey понятно, ну я вот как раз и хотел этот трай в методе заменить штатным механизмом внутри postgres ))

Comment: Т.е. вы желаете заменить запросы на вызов сохранённой функции, котораая выполнит новую запись?

Comment: Любопытно, а зачем ограничение такое? Просто логина не достаточно? Могу посоветовать завернуть это в транзакцию и в случае успеха/неудачи возвращать 1 или 0, причину сбоя можно определять по коду ошибки. Так же можно воспользоваться `RETURNING`, но там не будет ясна причина

Comment: @0xdb просто хотелось сэкономить на отдельном запросе к БД для проверки есть уже такой пользователь или нет. Чтобы метод который добавляет был не void а как в IO библиотеках бывает часто копирование файла с return флагом получилось/нет.

Comment: @Pavel Но это же прямо не следует из вопроса. По возможности поправте его на основе комментариев.

Comment: @0xdb все поправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with ins as (
  INSERT INTO users (id, username, login, password, email, create_date, success_level)
  VALUES (DEFAULT, (?), (?), (?), (?), now()::timestamp, (?))
  on conflict on constraint user_unique do nothing 
  returning id
)
select exists(select from ins) as success;
```

Postgresql 9.5 или новее. Для более старых надо будет писать хранимку с отловом исключений.

Comment: это было круто! А не могли бы немного рассказать что вы сделали? Особенно про `with ins as` ...

Comment: Что-то сложно выглядит. А можно обойтись только `insert ... returning id`? Есть id - запись вставлена, нет - не вставлена?

Comment: Обыкновенный CTE. Штука очень старая, не умеет её только тупой mysql. Позволяет структурировать запрос, в том числе пишущие запросы. on conflict - реализация синтаксиса для пропуска ошибки нарушения ограничений (как раз из-за него минимум 9.5 нужен, всё остальное уже очень старо). Returning id - возвращает значение и вставленной строки. Если ничего не было вставлено - будет 0 строк. Это затем в exists и проверяется, была ли хоть одна строка вставлена.

@Sergey, можно, разумеется. Но в условиях задачи было сказано получить true или false, поэтому так.

Comment: @Мелкий а почему `on conflict on constraint user` слово `on` используется 2 раза? `conflict` это зарезервированое слово? типо игнорирования возможного исключения?

Comment: Смотрите синтаксис insert'а. Выражение "on conflict", за ним опциональное ограничение "on constraint" с именем проверяемого ограничения. Далее действие, которое требуется выполнить при конфликте. "do nothing" соответственно ничего не делать. Если on constraint указан, то обрабатывается только конфликт этого ограничения, а другие (например, у вас email уникален ещё) - вызовут ошибку ограничения.